# Twilio permission to send sms has not been enabled for the region indicated

Tags: twilio

I'm a new Twilio user and am trying to test sending an SMS using my Live credentials, purchased From number, and valid To number.  I'm receiving this error:
Unable to create record: Permission to send an SMS has not been enabled for the region indicated by the 'To' number

AFAIK, sending IS enabled for the United States.  Is there something else that I'm missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Twilio says I don't have permission to send to the region of my 'To' number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30017182/twilio-says-i-dont-have-permission-to-send-to-the-region-of-my-to-number)

Answer (score 236):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

What you need to do is go to your Twilio console, to the [Geographic permissions for SMS section](https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/settings/geo-permissions) and ensure you have the permission checked for sending to the US.

Comment: The United States was checked but that still didn't resolve my issue.  Twilio Customer Support was able to resolve the problem.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: I have check in my Twilio console and my country (India) not selected. how i can check that or may i request to twilio support for this because i am unable to check?

Comment: @Shailesh If you're unable to check that, then please get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) who will be able to help you out.

Comment: As you said, i requested to Twilio support and now i am able to use Indian number also.Thanks.

Comment: @philnash I added a US number with call and SMS capability. When I go to the permissions section I am unable to checkbox any of the country. What can be the issue here?

Comment: @RajatSoni I'm afraid I don't know. I would check in with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) on that.

Comment: @philnash I did that but still get the error `[HTTP 400] Unable to create record: Permission to send an SMS has not been enabled for the region indicated by the 'To' number:`

Comment: @AbdellahRamadan Have you double checked that you have set the permission for SMS and not voice? If you are still having trouble I recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact).

Comment: @philnash I am not certain about which permission I am using. Can you please point where to set this permission? I enabled geographic permission but nothing.
Support have not replied yet since yesterday.

Comment: The Messaging Geographic Permissions here: https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/settings/geo-permissions. Ensure you have ticked the country you want to send SMS messages to.

Comment: worked for me! I did have to actually select the number FROM WHICH I am sending, not the one I am sending TO. But oh well, important that it worked! :)

Answer (score 20):

You can enable the region by checking the regions in Twilio Settings
[Twilio SMS Permission Settings](https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/settings/geo-permissions)

As I m facing the same issue "Permission to send an SMS has not been enabled for the region indicated by the \'To\ number", then I enabled all the regions and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 17):

You need to enable Geographic permission for the region were you want to send the sms to.
You can do that here
https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/settings/geo-permissions

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue but You have to add country code with ur number as well then it worked perfect

Comment: Exactly. They should add the numberprefix  in the code samples. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it for registration process consider using their "verify" service which allows international phone numbers instead  of the "programmable sms". Otherwise you have to manually enable the countries.

Comment: As an update, [Verify now has geographic permissions too](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/preventing-toll-fraud/verify-geo-permissions). This is part of our work to help prevent [toll fraud](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/preventing-toll-fraud) against Twilio developers.